# A bug in clang-4.0.0?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, clang++, auto

Seems there is a bug in [Non-type template parameters with auto type (P0127R2)](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) implementation of clang-4.0.0. Here is the issue:

```
// file main.cpp

template < int,  typename RR > void f1(RR&&) { }
template < auto, typename RR > void f2(RR&&) { }

class Class
{
    template < int,  typename RR > friend void f1(RR&&);
    template < auto, typename RR > friend void f2(RR&&);
};     

template < typename >
class ClassT
{
    template < int,  typename RR > friend void f1(RR&&); 
    template < auto, typename RR > friend void f2(RR&&);
};                                                

int main()
{
    f1<0>(0);
    f1<0>(Class{});
    f1<0>(ClassT<int>{});
    f2<0>(0);
    f2<0>(Class{});
    f2<0>(ClassT<int>{}); // FAILS ?!

    return 0;
}
```

The last line fails with `error: call to 'f2' is ambiguous` pointing to the definition of `f2` as one alternative and to the friend **declaration?!** of `f2` in `ClassT` as the second alternative. Like this:

```
main.cpp:26:5: error: call to 'f2' is ambiguous
    f2<0>(ClassT<int>{}); // FAILS ?!
    ^~~~~
main.cpp:4:37: note: candidate function [with $0 = 0, RR = ClassT<int>]
template < auto, typename RR > void f2(RR&& ) { }
                                    ^
main.cpp:16:48: note: candidate function [with $0 = 0, RR = ClassT<int>]
    template < auto, typename RR > friend void f2(RR&&);
                                               ^
1 error generated.
```

Is this really a bug or I am getting something wrong?

I am compiling with `clang++ -std=c++1z main.cpp` where `clang++ --version` gives

```
clang version 4.0.0 (trunk 284635) (llvm/trunk 284639)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: Bug. Clearly the declaration matching code wasn't updated to treat those two as declaring the same function template.